# pgAdmin. cannot input in drop down lists

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

My OS - Ubuntu 15.04.
For example, here, i cannot enter `Data type` by myself, but only chose from drop down list. It's very uncomfortably. Is it possible to fix?

[image: pgadmin input drop down list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, for pgAdmin for MAC OS X I am also not able to edit this (v.1.20), however, you can check raw SQL section where you can actually edit your DDL. [image]